# Disable Gridview position change on navigateback

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime

How to disable the scrolling on my gridView? When i click the back button after modifing my selected item.

as example u can create a default grid app [image: see visual studio project windows store templates]

if you created a app based on this template and now select the a item in the last list and then click the back button it will scroll to the beginning. But it should stay over the last list.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, you have an app with 2 pages the first page has a GridView with items, when you select one item you navigate to the second page with the selected item details, when you go back you want the scrolling in the GridView to be disabled, Right ?

Comment: @SamTheDev Its right. The GridView has about 5 Groups with another 5 Items. So if I want to select the last item in the last group I have to scroll to it. Now I'm in the Itemspage and when i go back to my page with the GridView, my screen scroll to the start of the GridView. Thats what i want to disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `goBack()` a new instance of the first `Page` is created, that's what causes the lost of your scrolling, to fix that make sure that the first Page is cached so you will navigate back to the same instance using [NavigationCacheMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode)

```
NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"
```